# Need help in getting the nativescript-viderecorder plugin to work

Tags: angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to get the nativescript-videorecorder to work on my android device. I used the script given in the github for nativescript-videorecorder plugin. However i am unable to get it to work when testing it on my connected android device.
When the say "Run on Device" the ui is shown on my device but when i click on the button nothing happens.
Below is the code for app.component.html:

```html
<!-- https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#page-router-outlet -->
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>

<ActionBar title="VideoCamera" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout orientation="vertical" row="0" padding="10">
    <Label text="Click the button below to record video"></Label>
    <Button text="Record Video" (tap)='onCam()'></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Below is the code for app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { VideoRecorder, Options as VideoRecorderOptions } from "nativescript-videorecorder";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

    onCam() {
        const options: VideoRecorderOptions = {
            hd:true,
            saveToGallery: true
        };
        const videorecorder = new VideoRecorder(options);
        videorecorder.record().then((data) => {
            console.log(data.file)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Which device you are testing it with? Did you try the demo project?

Comment: I am testing on Samsun S8. When i click the button it asks for permissions and nothing happens after i click on "Allow". I thought the above code is from demo but if i am wrong, can you help me with the link please.

Comment: Did you try testing on other devices to make sure it's not a issue with Samsung alone (in my personal experience, most time it will be issue with Samsung along may need special fix)? Try to run the demo app itself on Samsun S8.

Comment: I dont think it is an issue with the phone as i had already tested camera app and it works.

Comment: I didn't mean that your phone might have issues. I meant Samsung may need some extra code / special handling in some cases, so to narrow down whether it's a device specific issue with plugin I asked you to test with another device that's not Samsung.

Comment: @Manoj, i tested on another android phone (honor 9 lite) and it is exactly the same. I am really trying to get a working video recorder app using nativescript. If you have already tried that will you be able to give me the html and .ts code, so that i can try to understand where i might be going wrong.

Comment: I can confirm, it's the issue with plugin only. Something screwed up in latest version, I would suggest you to raise an issue at the plugin's Github repo.